# Android Studio cannot find local variable in debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-studio-4.0

When I try to debug my app, I can't see variables values in the debugger.

I have the following error when I try to evaluate an expression for instance (same with variables watchers) :

```
Cannot find local variable 'data' with type com.myorg.myapp.data.objects.DataToUpdate
```

The IDE seems to understand the type of my variable but it can't find it.

The variable is used just after so it has not been optimized away.

I belive that the code has been optimized but only part of it.

I built an apk and decompiled it with some decompilers online to see if it was minifyed or something.

- Part of my code is not

  - My class fields are ok, I can see their values in the debugger and their name is the same as in my code
- However, other parts of my code seem to be optimized (variables names are not the same)

  - E.g. : my variable "data" of type DataToUpdate becomes "DataToUpdate r118" in the decompiled code

I had nothing put in the `debug` buildType of my `build.gradle`. I added the following lines according to what I saw on the web to try to make it work :

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled = false
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
        }

}
```

I am using Android Studio 4.0 Beta 4 but it also didn't work reliably in Android Studio 3.6.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the logcat to understand and then correct the bugs in my code.

The debugger worked in other methods so it may be usefull to try to reproduce the problem in other methods, to debug it there.

A debugger working as expected would be better, but I couldn't make it work in this particular method.

Comment: Have you found a real solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did not use Android Studio for a while now. I think the problem appeared more often within threads or within lambdas, I don't remember very well.